# Advent T1 (All in one PC) - screen going blank

Tags: display, power-supply

I have an Advent T1 (all in one PC) that suffered from the under powered 12v 15amp PSU issue outlined [here](http://www.uktsupport.co.uk/advent/pc/t1.htm)  The computer would run for a short amount of time, and then power cycle.

I've replaced the PSU with one of the recommended 12v 18amp PSU's in the above article, and now it powers up ok, and stays on ok.  However, now the screen goes blank.

When you turn it on, you clearly see a bright display of the Advent BIOS splashscreen for 1-2 seconds, and then the screen goes blank.  Then after a few more seconds, you see the Windows XP loading screen for 1-2 seconds, and then the screen goes blank again.  Then after another 20-30 seconds you see a plain desktop with the mouse cursor in the centre of the screen for 1-2 seconds, and then the screen goes blank.  Moving the mouse or using the keyboard doesn't "wake" the monitor in this case.

What is strange is if I put a random boot CD in.  After the Advent BIOS splashscreen appears for 1-2 seconds and the screen goes blank, the boot CD menu appears for 1-2 seconds, and then the screen goes blank.  If I use the keyboard (blind) to select a boot CD option, and then press enter, the screen comes on again for 1-2 seconds (displaying the new section of the boot CD menu that I have just opened), and then goes blank.  This pattern repeats itself each time I blindly use the keyboard to change to a different boot CD menu page.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

I've taken the back off and had a clear out/vacum etc.  Didn't look too dusty, surprisingly.  A bit of surface dust on the fins of the fans that didn't come off with the vacum, but not a lot else.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this.
The problem with the T1 (&T100/200 models, too) was the Inverter Board used for the display.
These fail frequently (I have had several)
They're beyond repairing these days, sad to say... 
I'm just about to junk one - you can buy a 2nd hand all in one for less than I paid for a repair to the Inverter!
Cheers
Brian